# Setting alignment in source-data for optimal loading into memory?

Tags: c, memory-alignment, systems-programming

When defining a stream of data for a program to read into memory *(a file format for e.g. but could be any other kind of data streamed into memory).*

How should the data be alignment for optimal `memcpy`?

While `memcpy` doesn't require alignment, I've noticed its common for formats to write pad-bytes, aligning to 4 bytes for example *(even when the file's aren't memory dumps).*

I assume this is because its faster to operate on aligned data, however I'm not really sure about the details.

---

For common architectures, (X86, x64, ARM, PPC), (32 / 64 bits), on common libc implementations (glibc, freebsd, microsoft's... etc) ... is there some rule of thumb for aligning data for optimal reading into memory?

- Should 32 bit systems align to 4 and 64bit align to 8?
- Or is this unnecessary, where a fixed alignment is sufficient *(4 seems common)* for popular architectures - irrespective of their bitness?
- Or should (ideally) the data be aligned to each structures `_Alignof`?
  ... which may be impractical to implement since this will vary between systems.
  (making it preferable to fallback to some fixed value to simplify reading/writing)